# Is this psychological abuse? Should I switch supervisors?

Tags: advisor, science, abuse

I am in the third year of my four year PhD, which is funded by the department. My supervisor a week and a half ago called a meeting with me, after an email complaining about sending off an updated version of a manuscript to a conference without full approval. During the course of this meeting, when two others were present, he said a lot of things. However in this meeting he stated that I was on a "final warning" to be kicked out of the university (I had not received any previous warnings, and I'm not sure he has the capability to do this) and also his research group. He also said that he was engaging in a 'strategy of intimidation' so that I would be scared to make similar same mistakes in the future. I found this to be very worrying.

Following on from this he was especially nice via email, asking whether I would like to collaborate with a prestigious professor abroad. Indeed, the next day he spent 2 hours helping me prepare this manuscript, along with a postdoc.

This is part of a pattern of behaviour from this gentleman. Two months previously, after he said I shouldn't apply for IRB approval only weeks before, he had stated that I had committed severe ethical violations and that I should scrap the paper that I had worked on for the previous 7 months due to these violations. He also asked me whether I would like to go to jail for these violations.

Apart from this, my publication output has been relatively good. I got into a top journal in my field in my second year as first author.

I am very close to trying to switch supervisors and am just wondering, is this a stupid idea? Am I being overly sensitive? Is this psychological abuse?

Clarifications:

1. My aim here is not to raise a stink, I would be subtly switching supervisor, not reporting this to anyone, giving vague excuse of differences. I still have a lot of respect for the advisor as a scientist and fear of him.
2. If not clear enough in the initial question, part of my problem is that I was told not to go through the ethics process, then latterly reprimanded for not applying for ethics and committing unethical research. There may be a point here with regards to ethics in the first place.
3. I am thankful for some of the more hostile responses here, as they have made me aware of things that I may not have considered . Indeed they have made me aware of how this would be likely to be perceived. It has also made me slightly more cognizant of my own role in this.
4. I am a native speaker and have copied the quotes verbatim.

One final clarification:

Being asked too many questions here, will leave thread as is and not reply further. Thanks for all replies.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124612/discussion-on-question-by-john-is-this-psychological-abuse-should-i-switch-supe). Please see [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4230/why-do-the-moderators-move-comments-to-chat-and-how-should-i-behave-afterwards/4231) before posting a comment below this one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I am very close to trying to switch supervisors

Since you do not trust your advisor, switch.

Your descriptions show your advisor was dishonest, rude, and made counterproductive remarks.  The definition of abuse seems to hinge on what the abuse did to the victim's mental state; making you worried does not seem to fit the definition to me.  I'd suggest that instead of asking "Is this psychological abuse?" ask "Is this good supervision?" to which the answer is "No."

Comment: I do not see any dishonesty and rudeness. Can you explain?

Comment: @Louic Declaring 'strategy of intimidation' is probably neither dishonesty nor rudeness in the strict sense of the word. It is worse. It is a threat.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs A threat and a (final) warning are very different. This is not a threat: it is a last chance for OP to correct their mistakes. Very different from "psychological abuse". It is only fair to inform people that they have reached the limit of what is acceptable, and will be fired if it occurs again.

Comment: @Louic If what OP reports is correct, explicitly saying "strategy of intimidation", that sounds like a threat, not a warning, sorry. If you really wish to warn somebody, you do not meta-strategize in front of that person. That's something you do in a humorous context (which doesn't fit the bill here), or if you wish to display utter cynicism (which speaks for a ruthless supervisor). Of course, OP may underreport other parts of the occurrences, and that may sway my opinion, but we need more information for that.

Comment: @Louic You claim it's a warning, but the thing the asker is being warned about is very probably not something that can happen.  So it's not a warning.

Comment: @Louic I recently watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iq-LWnNRLVA.  How is this any different than a shark attack?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I think the announced "meta strategy" makes perfect sense in this situation that is clearly nowhere near a humorous context: if nothing else has worked in previous conversations, the professor gives a final warning. The professor feels bad about having to resort to this strategy, and therefore explains that they had to do so in the same conversation where they are using it.

Comment: @Louic Even if that were so, actually explaining a strategy of intimidation is prone to reduce the actual effect. Once you explain it, you either reduce its effect, or it can be construed as a form of bullying rather than what it is supposed to effect, namely delineating strict red lines. In top politics, you practical *never* get meta-strategies presented publicly - there's a reason for that. Anyway, OP needs to let us know more about the context for better advice.

Comment: @emory Having both worked in a lab and worked my way through boot camp, nothing that happened to him is likely to qualify as a boot camp "shark attack".  In the boot camp "shark attack" multiple DIs coordinate to increase confusion and fear, and the relative novelty of not being in the military or understanding terminology add a layer of disorientation.  It is a designed plan to create stress.  The professor's plan might also create stress, but he's not trying to disorient, confuse, and panic his audience.  Some of that happens anyway, but the prof is trying to explain, not disorient.

Answer (score 52):

You write that your advisor said that you "committed severe ethical violations."  But you don't say anything about what specifically you did, whether the accusations are true, or how you responded to that accusation.  We simply cannot give you good advice without knowing more about these violations.  Honestly it sounds like you don't understand what the accusations were, which is extremely worrisome!

It's sadly common that there are advisors who are abusive bosses, but this is not one of those common situations!  Either your advisor is completely disconnected from reality and is making up ethical violations, or you are a serious danger to your research group because you commit bad ethical lapses and don't bother to understand what you did or how to avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 28):

It sounds to me like your professor has noticed a pattern of poor decisions on your side, and they cannot handle another one. Professors are human beings, and this one seems to have reached their limit. Whether they are being reasonable or overreacting is hard to judge without knowing all the details of your interactions and collaboration.

But your professor is acting *very professionally* by not letting their serious warnings affect the way they collaborate with you directly afterwards: being nice and supportive after a serious warning is an excellent way to try and remedy the situation and give you all the possible chances to succeed.

An important question is whether the professor is right or not, and if the stern warnings are reasonable, or an overreaction. Again, this is impossible to tell without having been there and having seen all your past interactions, but to me it sounds like they may indeed have a point in the two cases you describe:

- It is true (but rare) that people go to jail for violating ethics: the professor is asking you, in no uncertain terms, to take ethics more seriously. Violating ethics is serious academic misconduct and could indeed be a valid reason for being kicked out of a university.
- submitting an "artefact" (do you mean abstract?) without explicit approval of all co-authors is generally considered very bad from, and depending on the exact circumstances even bordering on academic misconduct (associating your professor's name with ethically questionable research, for example). The professor is telling you clearly that this is *not done*, and that you should take more care next time.

If you think you can prevent the (serious!) mistakes the professor has warned you about, and they are indeed being nice towards you outside of the warnings you have received, I would recommend trusting your supervisor and learning from your mistakes.

However, I do want to emphasise again that without knowing the details of the interaction between you and your professor, it is hard to judge if a line was crossed during these interactions: you, and possibly your colleagues are the only ones who can judge this. If you have a colleague you trust, and who knows the professor, it may be helpful to ask their opinion on this matter.

Comment: "contacting an ethics committee only a few weeks in advance"  That is not what the question said.  It said the supervisor said not to apply weeks before the supervisor's subsequent statement.

Comment: Can you explain where you see the *pattern of poor decisions*? Or are you inferring this from the profs behavior? I can only see two instances of differences of opinion.

Comment: downvote, you are making excuses for an abusive person. Would you pursue a "strategy of intimidation" in any of your dealings with any other human? What kind person not only does that but tells the victim to their face that they are doing it knowingly and calculatedly? This is not a hard-done-by kindly professor at the end of their tether, they are a calculating pathological user. To the OP: supervisors that make you feel confident and good about yourself as their "strategy" for "helping" you succeed do exist. You deserve one of those.

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica  The question gives two examples of poor decisions. I am inferring that either (1) the professor thinks that these decisions are so poor that they constitute a pattern, or (2) that other, possibly smaller, mistakes have been made that lead the professor to give a "final warning". I also clearly state (3 times) that this is hard to judge without having been there, but these mistakes are serious and I can totally understand that the professor is angry.  Furthermore, I see no evidence of abusive behaviour: the risk of losing a job over the given "mistakes" is realistic.

Comment: OP's post suggests that the advisor's mood/attitudes are swinging wildly which is definitely indicative of the advisor being potentially unstable

Comment: The present question makes the (unsaid) assumption that OP has not presented the full context of the situation. Instead of giving an answer based on this premise (yes, it is kept as a question mark, but I think this needs really better clarification), I think OP should be asked concretely if there is more to the situation with the ethics approval and the artefact than they have let on.

Comment: @benxyzzy *Would you pursue a "strategy of intimidation" in any of your dealings with any other human?*  If I had tried a positive strategy and failed, it is not unthinkable that I might say something like, "I have tried many times to use a supportive approach with you, but have failed.  So now, regrettably, I have to try intimidation instead.  If you (do X) one more time, (you will face consequence Y)." This seems unreasonable in the current climate only because so many people deliberately feign extreme emotional fragility in naked ploys to seek advantage.

Comment: @tbrookside sounds a lot like reversing victim and offender to me. You just called literal intimidation reasonable if the target isn't playing ball, while framing the target's complaints as the truly malevolent wielding of power

Comment: The only answer this site can give to this type of questions. Plus 1.

Comment: I can't comment on the academic issues, as it's out of my domain of knowledge, but I cannot imagine ever saying "I will pursue a strategy of intimidation". If the relationship has devolved to that point, better to terminate it than say something like that. Wow. So there may be two issues here, but problems on OP's side don't excuse bad behavior on the part of the professor.

Comment: @benxyzzy If a toddler is doing something about to get themselves killed, a good parent will raise their response to whatever level necessary to prevent that from happening, including yelling at them, even if ordinarily yelling at a toddler isn't a great parenting strategy. The phrasing in OP's question about a "strategy" sounds a bit odd to me, but we don't really have the whole story. If OP is facing serious consequences if they don't change behavior, their advisor would be doing a disservice if they didn't pull out all the stops.

Comment: @BryanKrause but OP is not a toddler, they're not going to get themselves killed, and their supervisor is not their parent...

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica The 'pattern of poor decisions' can be inferred by both the 'final warning' (usually given after many other warnings) and the OP's own words "This is part of a pattern of behaviour from this gentleman."

Comment: How can one go in jail for breaking ethics in computer Science research??? I never hears of this.

Comment: @benxyzzy It seems OP could be participating in ethical lapses that could get them kicked out of the program or result in sanctions on the lab or university (they are frustratingly vague about it but it sounds like they failed to get approval prior to doing human subjects research). In this context, their advisor is the closest thing to a parent they have and they're about to have their academic career killed. If this is all true, and the message isn't getting through, it's time to get their attention.

Comment: @BryanKrause sounds a bit machismo to me, which I don't think comes off so impressive when it's a superior bearing down on an entry-level subordinate. I repeat: supportive and secure atmosphere is generally and widely understood to be a better way to get optimal behaviour out of people than throwing your weight around and pressurising

Comment: @benxyzzy It sounds like the supervisor has already said this is a problem in a lesser way without change. Now they felt they needed to escalate to make clear the severity. Calling out the "strategy of intimidation" may have been intended to soften the blow a bit by preparing for what's coming next: you aren't getting it, so I need to make sure you are clear of the consequences which include expulsion and legal issues. They aren't threatening to gain something for themselves, but to protect the student from harm. That's not "throwing weight around".

Comment: OP isn't the "victim" if their own ethical lapses are at issue. An advisor would be turning them into one, though, if they didn't make clear how serious these issues are and let them continue to stumble into trouble.

Comment: @looktook Who said anything about Computer Science?

Comment: @looktook, i suppose you can commit fraud doing federally funded research.

Comment: @Daniel Hatton OP said it is CS

Answer (score 6):

A more important question is whether or not you can actually switch, and what the consequences, if any, will be for doing so. You say you are in your third year and graduating next year - I interpret as meaning you are graduating spring 2022, which is 1 year away. Does your program even allow switching advisors so late? If you did switch advisors will your current advisor still have to be on your committee, considering you have done a considerable amount of work with them? How will switching advisors impact the letters of recommendations you receive when you are applying for your next position after graduating? More importantly, who would actually be your new potential advisor?

If you had another 3 or even 2 years before graduation, switching advisors should be pretty easy. When you only have 1 year left? Your priority right now should be to wrap up your dissertation research and prepare your applications for the coming hiring cycle.

You should consider that you will only have to endure this situation for 1 more year before you will move on to something bigger and better. Just putting some distance between you and your advisor could be a feasible solution.

Comment: Enduring bad behavior is often the same as enabling it.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist It is cheaper to expect others to pay the price for standing up to principles.

Comment: I am not sure that OP has as much time to finish their PhD. If the supervisor has kicked in his new strategy now, he has OP in the crosshairs and can be easily triggered.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Sure, but in this case the price of doing nothing is already pretty high.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I am not sure which of my comments you respond to. My comments are to be read separately. One is directed to you, the other to Taw. Your response seems to address a combination of my comments?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I did not read your second comment.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Well, then it does not really address the issue. You talk about "enabling" - this is putting the burden of the bad behaviour on OP. As if they are responsible and they have to sort it out. If it's indeed the supervisor's fault, then getting through the last year may indeed be the more plausible strategy. It's not about enabling.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs "Enduring" bad behavior is often enabling.  The asker wants to know if they should do that; I say don't do it.  I have no comment on what the asker might have done in the past, as no information was provided.  Promptly finishing the degree and leaving is neither enabling nor enduring.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I do not so much like the word "enabling", because I would say that the word "enabling" implies a real choice. (I do not consider choices here that amount to self-destruction).

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Well, the question claims there is a choice.

Comment: Another important question is, even if possible, would another advisor pick up the student?

Comment: @ScottSeidman exactly

Answer (score 6):

Before dealing with your professor, who did cross a line by stating he'd be using intimidation as a tool, you must ask and answer (to the best of your ability) how honest are you with yourself?

Most professors don't take this approach unless there were prior incidents which indicate that you have ignored earlier problems and corrective feedback.  It is always possible you have a professor that is a horrible person; but, it is far, FAR, more likely that you have a professor that has formed an idea that you are not manageable.  This idea might be supported by facts; but, even if it isn't, you need to provide evidence through your actions that you can work with him.

Your work in a lab under his name is not independent because everything you do carries his name on it, whether your or he likes it or not.  If you present something with a flaw in it, it will reflect on his lab long after you've graduated or dropped out.  You must understand his point of view, or you will not be able to work with him.  You submitted work to a conference without review, work that is expected to require some review because you're not an experienced, independently vetted, professor.

Maybe the work was excellent; but, there's a high chance that extra sets of eyes could have improved upon it.  Odds are the work wasn't that great, and you may know that, as you decided it couldn't stand up to review and submitted it without his review or knowledge.

So yes, you can use his wording to point out he's crossing a line; but, these investigations don't stop at what you submit.  They will see if you have "unclean hands" or in lay terms, "if you threw the first punch."   I doubt you would have enough of a stand to overturn that he should discipline you, and by your going public, there's a great chance that the discipline will have to be converted from "your prof being very angry with you" to real consequences (academic probation, reassignment to a different PI who has been warned of your prior conduct, likely resetting your research efforts to day one, and possibly dismissal from the school).

Play carefully, because every brilliant move is less brilliant when you don't consider the obvious responses which lead to you losing more than you would ever gain.  When you come to your decision on how to proceed, again ask yourself, "how honest are you with yourself" because you'll be inclined (as we all are) to think you're playing out a master move when in result you're just giving away every opportunity to win.

Answer (score 4):

The situation you describe is an uncomfortable one, and for what it's worth, I am sorry that you are going through it.  I tolerated similar behavior during my master's degree and tried to be more proactive during my doctorate.

The first thing that stuck me was your advisor **having others present** while reprimanding you.  *"Praise in public, punish in private."*  In my opinion, what they did was wrong.  Perhaps they were having a bad day, but unless your advisor specifically apologized for having done that, they may feel that it's acceptable behavior.  His admission that he was engaging in a form of intimidation is evidence that they think it is acceptable, and that statement, word for word, is something your should write down and share with anyone with whom you raise your concern.  **Intimidation is bad, openly admitting to doing it because they think they are allowed:  people have lost tenure for that.**

Now, all of the above assumes you were at fault in the first place, and it doesn't seem to me like you did anything wrong at all.  You mention that you were being given a "final warning."  I would take a moment and go back to the other times you advisor had "warned" you and see if there is any common thread among them.  I'm not defending your advisor here, I'm suggesting that you may want to have this information handy for the next part.  **Collect up emails, notes from meetings, etc. as your evidence to show this pattern of behavior in black and white.**

And the next part, is to approach your department's graduate program head; the person who oversees the overall progress of graduate students in your department to ensure they are making progress, and to be the first person to get involved in any advisor-student disputes.  A short email requesting a meeting to discuss the most recent reprimand, and then going over prior times to establish a pattern of behavior on the part of your advisor.  From there you can show that this was not a one time thing, that your advisor is handling things inappropriately, and that **it is adversely affecting you ability to move smoothly through your doctoral program.**  Say those words, because that point falls clearly within their purview.

The times when you advisor seems to have tried to make up for their behavior with nice emails and kind behavior after the fact is akin to other types of abuse.  **It's not ok**, because all your advisor is doing is covering their backside.  It's also a **sign of guilt on their part, because they know they are being abusive** and hoping they can wallpaper over the damage with niceties.  Don't fall for it.

After you've spoken with your grad program head, it's time to reach out to the department head, and repeat everything you discussed with the head of the grad program.

When you meet with the department head, in addition to everything you bring to the prior meeting, **come with the suggestion of at least one other advisor that you would be comfortable switch to**.  If you can have an off-the-record conversation with a prospective advisor asking if they could take you on as a student, that will help clear the way.  You department head will appreciate your boiling everything down to them making a decision, rather than asking them find a solution.  Department heads, are executives, and **the job of an executive is to make a decision**.  Give them one or more well-thought out options for them to choose from.  Otherwise, you risk them saying "I'll look into this, andget back to you," which may never happen.

Hopefully by this point, you'll have more than enough evidence to show a pattern of unacceptable behavior on your advisor's part, and a path to graduation by having an alternate advisor identified.  As long as you are being moved to another advisor, **your advisor's behavior is not your problem**, let the department head deal with it.  Your only responsibility is to provide any evidence you've collected from your experiences.

If none of this works, some universities have a Graduate College, whose job it is to oversee all graduate programs across the campus, covering all departments.  There should a Dean, or many Deans whose job it is to address issues like these when the department can't or won't take care of their own issues internally.  If it comes to this, **make sure you've also collected emails and notes from conversations with your grad program head, and department head to show that you've gone through the proper channels.**

It's a not a fun process.  I've been through a form of it, but I am nonetheless glad that I did.  I stood up for myself and in the end graduated.  There was no retribution from anyone, I was able to find employment without issue, and can tell you with confidence that your own moral compass is something worth listening to in times like these.

Comment: "Intimidation is bad" - I agree. "it doesn't seem to me like you did anything wrong at all" - emphatically not clear: OP says that they submitted an artefact without approval by other authors, and mentions irregularity on ethics approval. Maybe the infringements are minor, but the scope is wide and the latter can cost the PI their grants or more. So, while a fair advice to an innocent OP, the situation may be more involved than it seems.

Comment: You state "...having others present while reprimanding you. 'Praise in public, punish in private.' In my opinion, what they did was wrong."  My response: The post contains one side of the story.  I actually think the presence of witnesses contradicts the narrative being given by OP.  At my institution it is common to ask witnesses, such as the department chair or student liaison, to be present for a student/faculty meeting where a serious infraction will be discussed.  Those witnesses are there to protect the faculty member from potential charges of abusive behavior.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I have to plead ignorance on this because I don't know what an "artefact" is, at least not spelled that way.  If by artefact they meant "abstract" then yes, that is unprofessional.

Comment: @pjs I agree with you in principle, but literally every post on SE tells one side of the story.  We can only give feedback (if we give any at all) based on what we have.  I may be interpreting the OP's statement wrong, but when I read "two others", I read that as "two other students", not "two other people who might be faculty, staff, or administration."  So on that I fully admit my read of the situation could be wrong.

Comment: @iwantmyphd I took "artefact" as "something" or "widget" - yes, it could be an "abstract". I would expect a 3rd year PhD student to know what an "abstract" is, so mentioning it twice in the question means it's something else. If they did not know it's called an abstract, this would be a warning flag to themselves that they may be seriously out of touch as to what is appropriate as member of a research group and they may want to revisit the situation as a whole.

Comment: @iwantmyphd While every post on SE presents their side of the story, we're certainly justified to note inconsistencies or consider and discuss alternate explanations based on our own life experiences.  If the faculty member overstepped, there are witnesses.  If the wording was not as stated by OP, again, there are witnesses.

Comment: @iwantmyphd The tactic of punishing in public typically (I don't know about this case) only comes after punish in private fails.  The hope is that after a few private reprimands, a public one will help prepare the team for what is likely to follow (or at least make them aware of the issues, so they are not surprised).  I think the Prof's language he used was bad; but, if the evidence supports the same course of action, the same outcome would be proscribed regardless of the language.

Comment: The "other people" make this feel like an intervention to me.

Answer (score 3):

> he had stated that I had committed severe ethical violations and that
> I should scrap the paper that I had worked on for the previous 7
> months due to these violations

If this is accurate, it really seems to me like you've been accused of Research Misconduct, and this is a big deal.  I could be very wrong, but you're not providing any form of clarification, so this answer relies on this assumption.

Research misconduct is a big deal;  a potential career ender for you, as the offender, and for your supervisor, if they knowingly let any findings involved with the misconduct out the door.

This would certainly take a supervisor way out of their comfort zone.  Protecting their career may be their first impulse.  There is a strong possibility that there has been discussion of this situation with your chair and your Dean.  If not, there probably should have been.

The meeting with "others" strikes me as an intervention to attempt to correct your behavior, or perhaps your advisor wanted witnesses around to confirm the details of the meeting.  Of course, it would help if you could share who the "others" are, but I understand your reticence.

So, if you did commit research misconduct, I think your adviser's actions, in which he finds a way to prevent further misconduct and provide you with interesting educational opportunities ending with you getting a degree, while possibly not perfect, might be acceptable  (people don't tend to have much practice responding to such situations).  I would certainly believe him when he says this is your last chance.
Also, if you did commit misconduct, your realistic choices might be limited, as it is unlikely another supervisor would pick you up.

Again, I could be entirely wrong here, because you won't share details, but this is my "between the lines" read on your situation.  Only you can gauge how close your actions come to misconduct.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a good practice with dealing problems that could endanger a project, intellectual property, etc, is the use of **rules** (you should be given those rules from the start or at the first violation) and **escalation** (there should not be no radical step or measure at the first violation), eg., 1 warning + **informations (what was done, the consequences, the reasons for which is it wrong)**, 2 warning + light measure(s) , 3 fire + measure(s).

If your supervisor is not mentionning the rules of the lab/university at the first warning, or is lying about them, or is **acting or communicating inconsistently** (eg., different messages depending on present witnesses), or is involving **hidden or implicit pieces of information** including **personnal judgements/comments/features (ethny, gender, appearence, behavior etc)** or **blurry consequences**, or is using some sort of **surprise** (when you know the rules, there should not be any surprise at all), or is invoking some subtexts or surprising and strong moods. Then it is psychological abuse (sometimes named moral abuse).

The ideal communication in case of problem should be **at all times extremely clear for the present and the future (predictable), written, objective, with escalations and as cold as possible (without any kind of mood, affect, surprise)**.

If there is psychological abuse, I recommend to document everything (and try and document everything (voice record, email/chat copy) from the first suspect communication), and refer this to the chief of doctoral school to request piece of advice for your next steps and report the case.

The same way, you are subject to rules, warning, explanations and escalation, your supervisor is also subject to them for the problem involved. If there is no possible or desired resolution (you may feel permanently uneasy to finish you PhD), then indeed do switch your supervisor, again with the recommendations of your doctoral school's chief.

Comment: I think the use of bold formatting for emphasis in this answer is distracting and does not help in highlighting the important points, which are otherwise reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your boss is far from the best boss, but could not tell whether good or not for your research career.

Based on your record (the first author on the top journal), your future can be promising. Of course, although it depends on the field you are, you might be able to find a  good place to continue your research after recieving phD.

So, I feel two points look important: Will your boss give you phD; After getting phD how will the relationship between you and your boss last. I guess you can see old members of your lab to get information about this points.

If it is possible for you to receive phD and, afterwords, get a position for another PI, staying current place is worthwhile. Unless so, switching a supervisor might be good choice.

In any case, a stable state of mind is very important in research. Your boss seemed to be having a negative impact on your mental state, maybe in the short term. If you feel this way, I suggest you use a school counselor where your privacy is protected.

Answer (score -4):

**TL;DR.** *Get out, get out, get out!* If you can... I don't what field you're in. Changing supervisors may not be feasible. Is there a suitable alternative supervisor whom you could work with?
Fair or not, these are statements that need to be considered before making a definitive move.

That said, I am very sorry for this horrible, abusive situation you are in.
It is not fair on you.

---

Intimidatory behaviour is not acceptable. There are arguments as to whether *parents* should be allowed to discipline *their children* like that---I am not commenting on this---but certainly a *supervisor* should not behaviour like this towards a *student*. Trying to scare you with "go to jail comments"---disgusting.

I worked with someone who treated me extremely badly during my PhD---although it sounds nothing like as bad as your case! Sometimes we had disagreements about whether to look into certain questions; he wanted to investigate something, but I didn't. This is fine by itself, but he *explicitly* told me that his time was more valuable so I should investigate it and get back to him. The fact that I didn't want to didn't matter. He told me that he's the senior collaborator so I should do it. Incidentally, he was a postdoc when we started and had just got a permanent position when we finished.

I won't go into further details regarding his behaviour---it's not relevant to your question. I should have tried harder to end the collaboration earlier, in hindsight. I *really* regret this. His behaviour made my life miserable for months and months. I'm done with the collaboration with him now and I am *so much happier!* I've found lots of other people to collaborate with who are not toxic and treat me with respect.

This person wasn't my supervisor, but rather a collaborator. My supervisor went "supervision-AFK" with me about 1.5yrs, so I was working with other people therein. I'm in maths, so choosing with whom I work is relatively easy. I didn't even have the option of working with my supervisor for half my PhD, as I said. Changing supervisors is more of a big step than changing collaborators. I don't know exactly what field you're in, so I don't know how easy it would be to just not work with your supervisor but work with others instead? Not a perfect solution, but perhaps better than your current scenario.

Unfortunately, there's very little accountability in academia. People who hold power have little to no training in *utilising*, not *abusing*, this power. You can report this, but I highly doubt you have proof that he said these things---after all, who gathers proof of all interactions? I don't. It can also negatively affect people's perception of you. Lots of people will have had only positive interactions with this guy---not all toxic people are toxic *all the time*---and will try to defend his behaviour. Just look at other answers here. Imagine the response from his peers?

One answer suggests that you *intentionally didn't get his review on your work because you thought it wouldn't hold up to his critique*. Quite where the answerer got this information, I have no idea. You say it was an *updated* manuscrip without *full* approval. There was no indication in your question that you were intentionally. His behaviour is abusive, regardless of your mistakes.

In a fair world, you would report this person, their behaviour would be investigated and they would go on some type of supervisor-training programme. Alas, *in a fair world*...

Comment: To be fair to the other responders, while in isolation, I would have full sympathy for OP, there are a number of iffy issues, such as submission of an artefact [or abstract?] without approval by coauthors and some inconsistency concerning ethics approval. We do not know whether the supervisor gaslighted them or this was a misunderstanding, but there are things that absolutely cannot be done without such an ethics approval and a 3rd year PhD student will know that (even if the supervisor said something else). Your response takes the absolute position that OP is perfectly in the right. Perhaps.

Comment: There is a whole spectrum of academic misconduct, and, unless OP clarifies, there may be the possibility (I am not saying this is the case) that OP's cavalier attitude might have endangered the legitimacy of the whole group; university may have initiated an investigation against the supervisor, possibly suspending them, freezing or disbanding the group, possibly forcing retractions of papers? Something like that can scare the world even out of a tenured prof. OP does not mention any issues from previous years, only of this last sequence of events. This may indicate something triggered this.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs My response certainly does not take the position that te OP is perfectly, or even at all, in the right. It is not supposed to comment on this either way. If you can show me where it appears that way, I shall definitely edit to remove that implication! The point is that it's no excuse for abusive behaviour. Intentionally trying to scare a student. Disgusting. Absolutely vile. Such a shame to see so many people sticking up for abusive behaviour. No surprise that people don't report it

Comment: Sorry, I am the last person tolerating abuse. However, your whole mail operates under the assumption that OP has been abused. Which is possible and, if so, it's inexcusable. However, critical information is missing in the question and OP has *not* provided yet clarification. Until that is resolved, it can not be excluded that something weird is going on. You will see that my comments throughout the threads vacillate between wondering whether the supervisor is gaslighting or OP is not entirely forthcoming. The consensus in academia.SE is condemning abuse of OPs, but here's something off.

Comment: 'Trying to scare you with "go to jail comments"---disgusting'  Would you still think it disgusting if OP really had committed a crime that typically carries a jail sentence?  And if the supervisor felt that he'd been railroaded into helping OP cover up that crime and was understandably resentful about that?  Either possibility is wholly consistent with what we've been told in the question.

Comment: Kind of saw this one coming - OP's question was all about seeing the worst case scenario for others while failing to see their own faults. Now they accept an answer with negative score that most validates them. They will probably try to leave their advisor and it won't work out well for them, unfortunately, but maybe ultimately the best for everyone.

Comment: Bryan Krause and Daniel Hatton. Good luck with your respective careers

Comment: @DanielHatton Um, _disgusting_ would be too far in that scenario. _Handled poorly_ would be better. But the OP states that the advisor _explicitly_ said they are doing a strategy of intimidation. Maybe I misunderstood, but I felt that it was clear that the advisor doesn't think the OP would go to jail for these, but rather is being intimidatory. Maybe this is a mistake on my behalf. If the OP clarifies contrary to this, I can update the answer accordingly

Comment: @BryanKrause If you reread my answer, you'll see I actually at no point say that the OP hasn't done wrong. It is not clear from their post if they have made errors, from the mundane to the serious, or not. I do not comment on this. But the advisor's behaviour is horrendous even from a worst-case point of view, ie even assuming that the OP has commited serious mistakes. || That said, I do agree with you that accepting this answer is inappropriate. This sort of question isn't really a "here's the right answer to accept" question

Comment: @user24601 OP has made it fairly clear despite the opacity of their question that they've made ethical mistakes. This answer downplays those mistakes, implying it's okay to submit things without other authors' approval or IRB. I think you've completely misunderstood what OP's advisor meant about their "strategy of intimidation" and are imagining something like what you experienced instead. It's completely unclear that any abuse has taken place, especially if the "strategy of intimidation" is to state the potential consequences for what has transpired: nothing unethical or abusive about that.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I do not doubt that you would not condone what you see as abuse. Perhaps we see things differently, though. From my view and experience I've gained in life, this is classic abuse. And that's even taking a worst-case view of the OP's behaviours

Comment: @BryanKrause Wow. Dear me. I _do not_ condone submitting parts of manuscripts without all authors' approval or any other potential voilations in the OP---I don't know what "IRB" is. Please back up claims with quotes. But to suggest that a "strategy of intimidation" is to state potential consequences... dear me... no wonder people are scared to report abuse

Comment: To reiterate, I really don't feel that this should be an _accepted_ answer. There is nothing inherently more correct about it than ones giving opposing points of view. On-topic or not, this is definitely an 'ask for advice' question

Comment: @user24601 - I accepted it to try and stop the thread. I regret posting this, but the moderators don't allow you to delete threads. Stack exchange is rather more full of vitriol than your average online forum. I wish I could provide more detail on the events, but i am not going to risk deanonymizing myself for these people.

Comment: @John I understand that and sympathise completely. I hope that you are able to resolve the situation. It should go without saying, but to be completely clear, you shouldn't take action based on the opinion of an anonymous poster without all information such as myself!

Comment: "His behaviour is abusive, regardless of your mistakes". IRB or equivalent is approval for human subjects research; research without this approval is illegal. OPs own description of the strategy is that it involved informing of consequences, and that OP's advisor hoped that awareness of these consequences would prevent them from future violations.

Comment: @John If you think this discussion here is "full of vitriol" you must be new to the internet. The discussion is full of controversy, yes, but still focused on facts. I am sure that you have reasons for not disclosing more details - the problem is that the question, as it stands, does not permit us (at least me who hasn't made up my mind yet) to be more supportive. You will notice that there are many questions on SE for anti-bullying advice and many helpful comments there. Maybe your mistakes were minor, but we do not know. You might have been led into a trap. Again, we do not know.

Comment: @John If it's anti-abuse advice that you seek and you do not wish to reveal more about your case, please check out other answers on academia.SE, there is quite a bit of advice on that. You have also made clear in your question that the discussion here showed you the weak points of your position, so, while unpleasant, maybe nonetheless it is helpful in finding the best and fairest solution for yourself. Good luck!

Comment: Why not accept AnonymousPhysicist’s answer?  I don’t fully agree with it, but it’s a good on-point answer that’s not a long rant.

Comment: @NoahSnyder [kekw](https://media.tenor.com/images/e67977be0e7bf84cd9fa3567515fd9a2/tenor.gif)